How can I use fontawesome in Delphi Text-Captions
I tried to use Unicode-Codes with a fontawesome font file on windows, but the icons are not showing. Instead I see a box with a question mark, indication something went wrong accessing the icon.
Maybe in the font files not all icons are included. Which other possibilities do I have to spicen up my application with some fresh icons?
The Caption is from an TMLDExplorerBarSection. Maybe there is a better alternitive with built-in-support for Icons in front of the text? Like in MenuItems where an icon can be displayed in front of the MenuItem.Caption.
Thanks in advance for any help or hints.
Nicolas
